# Simulating the earths orbit around the sun in 2 Dimensions. Issues with gravitational force and scale

Tags: c++, simulation

As the title says, I'm attempting to simulate the earths orbit around the sun. I'm having issues not only with scaling things down to workable numbers such as the mass of both bodies. But also calculating the position of the bodies based on the gravitational force. I'm using C++ with SFML.

The way I'm calculating gravitational force is like so:

```
sf::Vector2f F; 
F.x = ((G * sun.mass * earth.mass) / (sun.position.x - earth.position.x));
F.y = ((G * sun.mass * earth.mass) / (sun.position.y - earth.position.y));
```

Where G is `float G = 6.67 / 1e11;`

As for the mass of each body, I'm currently just using arbitrary values that are low enough to see what's happening and how they act, where the suns mass is about 330 times the earths. Which as I'm sure you can guess is not working very well. lol. I'm doing this because the real numbers are too large and it just returns "inf" or 0, regardless of the data type I use. I tried this:
 `sun.mass = 1.989 * pow(10, 30); earth.mass = 5.972 * pow(10, 24)`

I'm not too sure how to update the velocity and position of the objects based on these calculations. I tried just doing something like

```
body.velocity += F;
body.position += body.velocity;
body.position += body.velocity;
body.setPosition(body.position);
```

But this obviously is not correct as the body with less mass needs to be pulled towards the one with greater mass.

I've looked around for resources trying to find some information but most of it just goes over my head. It doesn't need to be perfectly accurate, just something approximate.

This is for a university project, I just have no real knowledge of physics so I'm really just learning as I'm going. Any help would be much appreciated.

I've tried adding the gravForce to the velocity, but I'm not sure how that works when a negative comes up? As the distance between the objects can be negative since I'm calculating it like this:

`sun.position - earth.position`

I guess I could normalize the vector?

Also not really sure how to make the object with less mass be pulled towards the one with greater mass.

Comment: *... the body with less mass needs to be pulled towards the one with greater mass.*  This is incorrect.  Both bodies pull towards one another.

Comment: *But this obviously is not correct as the body with less mass needs to be pulled towards the one with greater mass.* That's not how gravity works, both bodies get pulled towards each other.  For instance the sun is not the center pointer for all of the orbits in our solar and the barycenter can even be located outside the radius of the sun.

Comment: You have calculated F. Now you need to convert that to acceleration applied to each body `F = ma`. Once you have acceleration you can calculate the change in velocity, then you can add the velocity to the location. Once this is all done probably add a translation so that you keep the sun as the central reference frame.

Comment: A few notes here. Always use type `double` instead of `float`. I guess you used `float` because `sf::Vector2f` requires you to do so, in which case I suggest to write your own `struct` of doubles. As of the value of `G`, instead of defining it as `float G = 6.67 / 1e11;`, you can use scientific notation as well, like this: `double G = 6.67e-11;`, or, as I prefer, using direct initialization instead of copy initialization: `double G{ 6.67e-11 };`.

Comment: This trick (using scientific notation) will solve all the other issues.  I've done this simulation already and can confirm that, if instead of doing it the long way (`1.989 * std::pow(10, 30)`), you use scientific notation (`1.989e30`), it'll work just fine.

To sum up, use scientific notation, i.e. `1.989e30` for the mass of the sun, for instance.

Comment: Thanks. I realize both bodies pull towards each other, I just meant visually you will see the smaller one getting pulled far more than the larger one would.

Comment: You should recheck your formula. You have the gravitational potential which is the antiderivative of the gravitational force (you're missing a square in the denominator)

Comment: The most important"base" of physics is F = m * a, so the acceleration is a = F / m. And the change in velocity is acceleration multiplied by time. (The resource you need is your old physics book from high school.)

Comment: Also note its `F= GmM/(r^2)` You have not squared the distance.